# When chainging oil something fell in the engine

Tags: oil-change

So i was chainging oil and when i was piaring oil in engine something white went in the engine it was 2-3cm big i think a plastic peace or bubble  and i know i can kill the engine if it block something in the engine so im scared but i still drive it and i know that something can hapen at any time and i literly just got the car 5 days ago its a nissan pathfinder 2006
. And if it was a air bubble or water in the oil i know nothing bad can halen but if it was a plastic peace i afrajd to kill the engine does antone know what can hapen or what it was or how can i get it out?

Answer (score 1):

What engine ? In the Nissan Murano 3.4 V6 , the oil fill goes into one of the cam covers ( very much like the rocker covers of an American V8). Probably there are small drain holes at each end down to the pan, about 1 to 2 cm diameter. There is a good chance the foreign object will stop there , at least temporarily. Probably there is a screen on the inlet to the oil pump in the pan which will stop a small bit of plastic. So, PROBABLY no problem. The alternative is to pull the cam cover under the fill tube. That does not look like too bad a job on my 3.4 L , a few hours of nuts and bolts. If you find nothing , you could consider dropping the oil pan ; it looks like it could be wiggled out between the exhaust header and the frame on my 3.4 L Murano. In the good old days I would pull both rocker covers on my Olds in 10 minutes , but the covers knew what to do and I had the gaskets arranged so they did not need replacing.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot guess what it was.

What you do is remove the rocker cover or cam cover and see if the piece is sitting there, it will be if you are lucky.

If not, then you have to find it otherwise it may cause serious damage - even if it was only "plastic" it may well block oilways which can cause oil starvation and seizing.

Comment: I expect it is very likely there is a screen on the oil pump inlet, so some protection.

Comment: @blacksmith37 seen a screen that had been "sucked" onto the intake pipe so the effective opening went for 6 square inches to less than 1 inch square... so it was easily blocked causing partial seizing and severe damage over time.

Comment: Yes, I am going with "probably". Long ago , I pulled the screen out of an Audi as it was plugged with gunk. I may have left them out of a couple Buick 350 's to reduce restriction to the oil pump which was up in the block instead of the pan.